# How to control node layout in Graphviz?

Tags: graphviz, dot

`a -> b -> c -> d -> e -> f` draws straight vertical line of nodes. Why does adding `c -> e` shift node `d` to the left and how can I shift it to the right?
`c -> e` and `c -> f` shifts `d` and `e` to the left and shifts `f` to the right. How does this thing work?

```
digraph G {
  a -> b -> c -> d -> e -> f
  c -> e
  c -> f
}
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27091591/graphviz-dot-vertical-alignment-of-nodes can help you.

Comment: Thanks, it's very helpful. But I still can't understand why `c -> e` causing `d` to move left, not right.